# Selenium WebDriver with loaded Chrome Profile does not navigate to any URL

Tags: php, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using the following code to load the profile I use into Selenium WebDriver but it doesn't navigate to any URL (the profile is correctly loaded as I see my bookmarks)L.

```
$host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'; // this is the default
$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();


$options = new ChromeOptions();
$options->addArguments(array(
    '--user-data-dir=/home/sorin/.config/google-chrome',
));

$capabilities->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options);

$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities, 15000);

$driver->get('https://www.google.ro/search?q=test');
```

My versions are:

Chrome - Version 54.0.2840.71 (64-bit)

ChromeDriver - 2.24

Selenium WebDriver - 3.4.0

The code is working without the profile loading.

Thanks!

Comment: provide your selenium, chromedriver and chrome version.

Comment: I added them to the question. Thank you @kushal.

Comment: Try updating chromedriver to 2.28 or above

Comment: 2.28 is having the same behaviour and 2.29 errors out because it needs a newer version of chrome.

Comment: @SorinTrimbitas I work with Java, I can see the implementation of RemoteWebDriver as `org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.RemoteWebDriver(URL remoteAddress, Capabilities desiredCapabilities)` I wonder how you pass that `RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities, 15000);`

Comment: As of now, all I can say is, **profile loads successfully** but then it **crashes** :)